# Calling VB6 exe using VB .Net applications login credentials

Tags: .net, vb.net, authentication, process, vb6

I have a VB .net Windows application and on certain click i want to open a VB6 application , I used "Shell" to open the VB6 exe successfully but its obvious opening the login page. As the user entered the login credentials in the VB.net application already I dont want user to key in the credentials agian.

My effort:

```
Dim startInfo As New ProcessStartInfo()
startInfo.UseShellExecute = False
startInfo.FileName = "POS.exe"
startInfo.UserName = "ADMIN"
Dim testString As New SecureString()
For Each ch As Char In "pass1234"
    testString.AppendChar(ch)
Next
startInfo.Password = testString                       
Dim exe As Process = Process.Start(startInfo)
```

I did the above part in VB.net application and passed the UserName and password explicitly. But it is prompting the error as **"Unkown UserName or bad password"** .

Do i need to amend Vb6 application too on the project load? 
or
 To create some GLOBAL parameter in VB6 to catch the UserName or Password sent from VB.net program and to check if  these parameter exists then to perform the VB6 application's login screen's  login button click.

Comment: In VB6 you'll have to tell it to use the arguments you're passing to it, otherwise it will ignore them.  Mind you, if you have access to the source use this as a workaround and port it to .net so that it can be part of your existing project.  There are very few things that you could do with VB6 that you can't with .net

Comment: "if you have access to the source use this as a workaround and port it to .net " What things i have to port?    I have source of both VB6 and Vb.net but am not getting where to add the parameter.

Answer (score 0):

In VB6 you'll have to tell it to use the arguments you're passing to it, otherwise it will ignore them. Mind you, if you have access to the source use this as a workaround until you port it to .net so that it can be part of your existing project. There are very few things that you could do with VB6 that you can't with .net. To process command line arguments in VB6,. I think you want the [Command Function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa262696%28v=vs.60%29.aspx).

Comment: Can you suggest any link where command line argument has been used?  MSDN has no examples.

Comment: At the top of the page I sited is a link called example.